# Retrofit expecting an array not an object

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Hi I am new to the Retrofit 2.0 library, I am having problems parsing some json. I have looked at some other solutions on Stackoverflow but not having much luck with my problem. I am trying to call an api from android with retrofit 2.0.But it is throwing error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT.

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

> ```
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 2 path $
> ```

Fragment.java

```
ListView superListView; 
static Retrofit retrofit = null;

@Override
  public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

 connect2();
}

 private void connect2() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    HomeApiService movieApiService = retrofit.create(HomeApiService.class);
    Call<List<Movie3>> call = movieApiService.popularMovies2();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie3>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie3>> call, Response<List<Movie3>> response) {
       
            List<Movie3> myheroList2 = response.body();
            String[] oneHeroes = new String[myheroList2.size()];

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < myheroList2.size(); i2++) {

                oneHeroes[i2] = myheroList2.get(i2).getTitle();

            }

            superListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, oneHeroes));

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie3>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e("Error: ", throwable.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

HomeApiService.java

```
public interface HomeApiService {

     @GET("movie/test")
    Call<List<Movie3>> popularMovies2 ();
}
```

Movie3.java

```
public class Movie3 {
    
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
   
    public Movie3(String title) {
       
        this.title = title;
        
    }
   
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }  
}
```

Comment: add the json response with your question.......

Comment: This is the json response, needed to give as url because large https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=ffd597419be5a256066dc51c49bc659f

Comment: your POJO class is not correct.

Comment: Movie3 class? Im new to this so any help/example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...First of all your POJO for accepting the response is not correct. This is a crucial part while accepting a response. Your POJO should look like this :

```
public class Result{
    public boolean adult;
    public String backdrop_path;
    public List<int> genre_ids;
    public int id;
    public String original_language;
    public String original_title;
    public String overview;
    public double popularity;
    public String poster_path;
    public String release_date;
    public String title;
    public boolean video;
    public double vote_average;
    public int vote_count;
}
```

```
public class Root{
    public int page;
    public List<Result> results;
    public int total_pages;
    public int total_results;
}
```

Where root is the class and result is another class. As you can see the response contains result as a list.

And also the HomeApiService should look like this:

```
public interface HomeApiService {

     @GET("movie/popular?api_key=ffd597419be5a256066dc51c49bc659f")
    Call<Root> popularMovies2 ();
}
```

Hope you got the point. Add necessary getters and setters. Normally it's easy to use a JSON to POJO online converter. Here is one: https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo    ..... paste the response in JSON and get the POJO converted.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, the online json converter will be useful. Ive implemented both those but still stuck on the Fragment.java . How to use Call<Root> in Fragment.java?

Comment: Call<Root> call = movieApiService.popularMovies2();

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. I thought maybe you could reference "Root<List<Result>>" directly so not to get a multidimension response. Using "public void onResponse(Call<Root>call, Response<Root>response) {" I cant seem to get .size(); or .get(); methods

Comment: Root root = response.body();   ... this will do the trick.And also if this works then please accept the answer.